# HTML TinyMCE editor formatting issue for underline

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using the tinyMCE editor, everything works fine except for the underline. It does not render the underline in the editor but when clicking on the word shows that the word has been underlined.

[Please click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb9Bk.png)

Is there any way of bringing the underline into the editor too?

Have seen other solutions which added to my init function but this does not work either:

```
formats : {
        underline : {inline : 'u', exact : true}
        }
```

What i am loading into the textbox is:

```
<p><span><u>Action</u></span></p>
```

Comment: Do you specify any stylesheets (CSS)? The default look of the u tag might simply be overwritten by a stylesheet you are using.

Comment: @nosnahoj-trap After checking, there isn't any styles which are over writing this. Any suggestions on fixes?